# RemoteAttribute not passing querystring as IEnumerable<T> correctly

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Let's say I have a ViewModel like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AvailableBars { get; set; } /* For populating DropDownList */

    [Remote("CheckIds", "Baz", AdditionalFields = "Id")]
    public IEnumerable<int> BarIds { get; set; }
}
```

And a controller like this:

```
public class BazController
{
    // ...CRUD operations skipped

    public ActionResult CheckIds(int id, IEnumerable<int> barIds)
    {
        bool isValid = /* Logic for checking validity */
        if (!isValid)
        {
            return Json("Error", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

In my view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BarIds, Model.AvailableBars, new { multiple = "multiple" })
```

The problem is when I try to trigger the validation, the actual HTTP GET request becomes:

```
http://localhost:8080/Baz/CheckIds?id=4&barIds=7%2C8 /* <-- barIds=7,8 */
```

instead of:

```
http://localhost:8080/Baz/CheckIds?id=4&barIds=7&barIds=8
```

which the default model binder failed to bind the `int`s to `IEnumerable<int>`. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery.validate and jquery.validate.unobstrusive doesn't handle arrays.
If you really need to handle arrays, you need to modify them.

Shortest solution I can think of:

1) Modify the `$.ajax` call at the `remote` function of `jquery.validate` into this

```
var ajaxOptions = $.extend(true, {
    url: param,
    mode: "abort",
    port: "validate" + element.name,
    dataType: "json",
    data: data,
    success: function (response) {
        ...
    }
}, param);

//Fix the bug
//we are not supposed to pass functions to data parameter
//capture the function output so array values are
//serialized properly
$.each(ajaxOptions.data, function (key, value) {
    if ($.isFunction(value)) {
        ajaxOptions.data[key] = value();
    }
});

$.ajax(ajaxOptions);
```

2) Add `traditional: true` to the `remote` adapter of `jquery.validate.unobstrusive`

```
var value = {
    url: options.params.url,
    type: options.params.type || "GET",
    data: {},
    traditional: true //so that MVC is able to de-serialize arrays
}
```

Comment: I filed a bug report in JQuery.validation. [Link](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/954)